# DB2 runstats throws exception " The utility could not generate statistics. Error "-911" was returned.. SQLCODE=-2310, SQLSTATE= , DRIVER=3.53.71"

Tags: statistics, db2, query-optimization

Getting the below error when i run the following command :

call admin_cmd('runstats on TABLE schema.table with distribution and detailed indexes all')

DB2 runstats throws exception " The utility could not generate statistics.  Error "-911" was returned.. SQLCODE=-2310, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=3.53.71"

DB2 version - 9070900, table has 477125 rows. Marked as non-volatile.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What diagnostic information is in db2diag.log? The error -911 points at a locking/deadlock issue.

Answer (score 0):

Still waiting on the feedback regarding diagnostics, but from the error it seems like this is related to the table or an index being blocked due to other locks (deadlock or contention).
The db2diag.log should hold information on which other process has been involved. In addition `db2pd` could be used to look into the lock situation. Most likely runstats will run without any error when repeated some time later (reason for no feedback to my diagnostics question?).